# How would I get this function to stop repeating questions?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift5

I'm making a quiz app and I have a function that keeps repeating questions, this is the function:

```
    func updateQuestion(){
        if questionNumber < allQuestions.list.count{
        allQuestions.list.shuffle()
        questionsView.text = allQuestions.list[questionNumber].question
        optionA.setTitle(allQuestions.list[questionNumber].optionA, for: UIControl.State.normal)
        optionB.setTitle(allQuestions.list[questionNumber].optionB, for: UIControl.State.normal)
        optionC.setTitle(allQuestions.list[questionNumber].optionC, for: UIControl.State.normal)
        optionD.setTitle(allQuestions.list[questionNumber].optionD, for: UIControl.State.normal)
        selectedAnswer = allQuestions.list[questionNumber].correctAnswer

   }
```

My questions are stored in another class named QuestionsBank, how would I be able to get them to not repeat?

```
class QuestionBank {
    var list = [Question]()

    init() {

        list.append(Question(questionText: "What is his middle name?", choiceA: "E***k", choiceB: "E******o", choiceC: "G******s", choiceD: "He doesn't have a middle name", answer: 2))

        list.append(Question(questionText: "What is the name of his first dog?", choiceA: "Neka", choiceB: "Sadie", choiceC: "Bear", choiceD: "Jeffery", answer: 3))

        list.append(Question(questionText: "What is his energy drink of choice?", choiceA: "Monster", choiceB: "Reign", choiceC: "Rockstar", choiceD: "Bang", answer: 2))
    }
}
```

I feel like I would somehow need to assign tags to each of the questions to identify them but I don't know how to go about that. I'm new to programming so any help would be appreciated, although I may ask a lot of questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is to not shuffle the array in the `updateQuestion` function and instead do this at the end of your `QuestionBank` init method.

Now the question are randomly ordered and you use the `questionNumber` you already have to keep track of the next question.

Another but similar solution is to let the `QuestionBank` take responsibility to handle the question

```
class QuestionBank {
    private let list = [Question]()
    private var index: Int

    init() {
        var temp = [Question(questionText: "What is his middle name?", choiceA: "E***k", choiceB: "E******o", choiceC: "G******s", choiceD: "He doesn't have a middle name", answer: 2),
            Question(questionText: "What is the name of his first dog?", choiceA: "Neka", choiceB: "Sadie", choiceC: "Bear", choiceD: "Jeffery", answer: 3),
            Question(questionText: "What is his energy drink of choice?", choiceA: "Monster", choiceB: "Reign", choiceC: "Rockstar", choiceD: "Bang", answer: 2)]
        index = 0
        list = temp.shuffled()
    }

    func nextQuestion() -> Question? {
        guard index < list.count else { return nil }
        let question = list[index]
        index += 1
        return question
    }
}
```

and the update function would then be

```
func updateQuestion(){
    if let question = allQuestions.nextQuestion() {
        questionsView.text = question.questionText
        optionA.setTitle(question.optionA, for: UIControl.State.normal)
        optionB.setTitle(question.optionB, for: UIControl.State.normal)
        optionC.setTitle(question.optionC, for: UIControl.State.normal)
        optionD.setTitle(question.optionD, for: UIControl.State.normal)
        selectedAnswer = question.correctAnswer
    } else {
         // No more questions to ask, handle this here 
    }
}
```